# Why does my Interstitial iAd crash when there is no Internet connection?

Tags: ios, crash, iad, interstitial, internet-connection

I can't figure out how to restrict my Interstitial iAd to only show when there is an internet connection. I have implemented the `-bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` function and tried logging the error, but it never even gets called.

The result of my app trying to load an iAd without an Internet connection is a nasty memory issue, and a sudden crash.

I'm sure the solution is simple, but I can't find it anywhere else.

Comment: Edit your question to include how and where you are implementing your iAd interstitial. Also include the error you receive when it crashes.

Comment: That's not necessarily the issue. The crash has no log, it just quits the app. What I really am asking for is if there is some function I can call for the iAd to not appear when there is no Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're requesting an interstitial ad when an interstitial fails to load, resulting in an infinite loop of ad requests when there is no internet connection.

Here's a simple function to check for connectivity:

```
-(BOOL)canConnectToGoogle {
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    return ( URLString != NULL ) ? YES : NO;
}
```